# Faster way for emotion images using replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now i use for a chat js client:

```
chat = chat.replace(/\+best/gi, "<img src='./img/emotes/+best.png' class='chat'>");
chat = chat.replace(/\+cry/gi, "<img src='./img/emotes/+cry.png' class='chat'>");
chat = chat.replace(/\+hello/gi, "<img src='./img/emotes/+hello.png' class='chat'>");
chat = chat.replace(/\+pain/gi, "<img src='./img/emotes/+pain.png' class='chat'>");
chat = chat.replace(/\+smile/gi, "<img src='./img/emotes/+smile.png' class='chat'>");
```

There like 33of them, issue being obviously there might be a space, or directly a word behind it and or in front of it.

I have a feeling it can be done a whole lot faster, any one have any suggestion?

Comment: I can't back this up, but I've heard that regex is generally quite slow. Can't you use a straight up string replace w/o regex?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing complex pattern matching. You should be able to do a simple replacement of string characters here.

```
chat.replace("+best", "<img src='./img/emotes/+best.png' class='chat'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

*This will go through a space separated string of the image names, and replace them accordingly (even with spaces) and ignore it if it is apart of a word*

```
var emotes =
  ("best cry hello pain smile").split(" ");

for(var index = 0, emote; index < emotes.length; index++) {
  emote = RegExp(("\\b\\s*(\\+" + emotes[index] + ")\\s*\\b"), "gi");
  chat = chat.replace(emote, '<img src="./img/emotes/$1.png" class="chat">');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ES6 way to do the replacements in one line by passing a function to `.replace()`, which dynamically replaces the search text.

```
const emotes = ['best', 'cry', 'hello', 'pain', 'smile'];
const search = new RegExp(emotes.map( (emote) => '\\+'+emote ).join('|'),'gi');

chat = chat.replace(search,
  (match) => `<img src='./img/emotes/${match}.png' class='chat'>`);
```

Happy to explain any of the above if that's useful.